# How to bind Dynamic CheckboxList template in KendoUI

Tags: kendo-ui, checkboxlist

I wanted to bind a checkboxlist using KendoUI when a modal pop is opened.
On modal popup load I wanted to get data from a webapi which will have json response and bind it to checkbox kendo Ui template.

I referred kendoUI forums all samples are using static data. Can someone please guide me to the right direction where I can consume dynamic data.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a lot of ways to approach this.

I think the easiest way would be to use a TreeView with checkboxes configured that only returns a single level of nodes, then just show it in a Window or Dialog as you would show any other view.  This way you get decent, default item formatting of the TreeView with having to use a template, but you don't get paging if your datasource is large.

You can also use a ListView with a template that formats the data with a checkbox.  This requires a template but you get paging capability.  Once again, you just display the ListView in a Window or Dialog as normal.

Here's a simple demo of a ListView implementation: http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/iwOhIV

It is a combination of Kendo demos: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dialog/treeview-integration with the TreeView replaced with the ListView from this demo(http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/listview/remote-data-binding) and then the styling tweak with a template that uses checkboxes.

The rest of it is up to you(persisting/loading checked state, etc).

Comment: Awesome this is great. I will go with ListView implementation.

Comment: Great answer, I was looking for this everywhere but couldn't find any concise as this.